# Designing Rails Authentication API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, authentication, rest

I need users to authenticate through a form, but I also need to expose this authentication as an API for use by other applications/devices.

Obviously I want to keep things simple and avoid duplication, so how should I approach this? Should I use a single URI for both user login and api login? If so how should I handle the different requirements - inform the user of success or failure with a flash/redirect and return a JSON object to the API client?

Answer (score 2):

Use a form based login for your users (e.g. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise))

and an [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) based login for the API (for rails [oauth2_provider](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/oauth2_provider))

You cannot avoid duplication here, not if you want to do things correctly. Mainly because your API is stateless and your users are stateful (the cookies!).

Comment: But what if I use token-based authentication? Would that mean there was a way of unifying the User login and API authentication?

Comment: oAuth is a bit more than an access_token only, you have to sign every request. The spec says that you can obtain an access_token sending your password, but it's not recommended. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#page-14
Rails is full of gems doing all those things already, you won't have much to do, regarding duplication.